# Grafana specific dashboard CSV exporter with python

Tags: python, api, grafana

I have a grafana instance running inside a container. I am developing a python code that connects to grafana and exports some specific dashboard data for a given time range specified in the code.
When I run the code, I get a 404 error.
I have checked the url the grafana API key, and all works fine.
Note: time range selection is not implemented yet.
The code:

```py
import requests
import csv

def export_dashboard_to_csv(api_url, dashboard_slug, api_key, csv_filename):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    url = f"{api_url}/api/dashboards/db/{dashboard_slug}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        dashboard_data = response.json()
        panels = dashboard_data["dashboard"]["panels"]

        with open(csv_filename, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for panel in panels:
                panel_title = panel["title"]
                panel_data = panel["data"]
                writer.writerow([panel_title])
                writer.writerow(panel_data)

        print(f"Dashboard exported to {csv_filename} successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to export dashboard. Status code: {response.status_code}")

# Example usage
api_url = "http://IP:3000"
dashboard_slug = "l9W36T24z"
api_key = "****"
csv_filename = "./dashboard_data.csv"

export_dashboard_to_csv(api_url, dashboard_slug, api_key, csv_filename)
```

I expect the script to connect to the url with the API key and export the data from specific panel and dashboard, and then change its format to CSV.

Comment: You are using wrong endpoint https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/dashboard/#get-dashboard-by-uid